# Using OpenLayers with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I'm a new user of QGIS and OpenLayers. I had used it some time ago, then I had to format my PC and reinstall all programs. After this operation, I've found I cannot use OpenLayers because the following window appears.

[image: python-related error window]

Answer (score 2):

What I can see from your screenshot is that your project is not set to EPSG3857.

Try changing the project-crs to 3857.